# Remove Text between <a></a> but not the href or <span></span> using PHP

Tags: php, strpos, string-length, strip-tags

Trying to remove text from between `</span>` and `</a>`. I want to just remove the `some text here` just after the `</span>` so that it only shows the icon.

```
$bad_string = '<li class="someclasses"><a target="_blank" href="http:www.example.com/dir/handle"><span></span>some text here</a></li>';

$good_string = '<li class="someclasses"><a target="_blank" href="http:www.example.com/dir/handle"><span></span></a></li>';
```

What currently echoes:

```
<ul id="menu-social-menu-1" class="menu">
    <li class="someclasses"><a target="_blank" href="http:www.example.com/dir/handle"><span></span>some text here</a></li>
    <li class="someclasses"><a target="_blank" href="http:www.example.com/dir/handle"><span></span>some text here</a></li>
    <li class="someclasses"><a target="_blank" href="http:www.example.com/dir/handle"><span></span>some text here</a></li>
    <li class="someclasses"><a target="_blank" href="http:www.example.com/dir/handle"><span></span>some text here</a></li>
    <li class="someclasses"><a target="_blank" href="http:www.example.com/dir/handle"><span></span>some text here</a></li>
</ul>
```

What should echo:

```
<ul id="menu-social-menu-1" class="menu">
    <li class="someclasses"><a target="_blank" href="http:www.example.com/dir/handle"><span></span></a></li>
    <li class="someclasses"><a target="_blank" href="http:www.example.com/dir/handle"><span></span></a></li>
    <li class="someclasses"><a target="_blank" href="http:www.example.com/dir/handle"><span></span></a></li>
    <li class="someclasses"><a target="_blank" href="http:www.example.com/dir/handle"><span></span></a></li>
    <li class="someclasses"><a target="_blank" href="http:www.example.com/dir/handle"><span></span></a></li>
</ul>
```

Using this below code in WordPress the text after the span is still present. It won't strip out the text after the `</span>`. What's my mistake? here:

```
<?php if ( has_nav_menu( 'social-menu' ) ) {
    $menu = wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'social-menu', 'fallback_cb' => '', 'echo' => false ) );

    function convertURL($menu) {
        return preg_replace("/<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"([^\"]+?)\"><span><\/span>.*?<\/a>/", "<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"$1\"><span></span></a>", $menu);
    }

    echo $menu;
    }
?>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just solve that with a regex?

```
function convertURL($url) {
  return preg_replace("/<a href=\"([^\"]+?)\">.*/", "<a href=\"$1\"><span></span></a>", $url);
}
// input:  <a href="http:www.example.com/dir/handle"><span></span>some text here</a>
// output: <a href="http:www.example.com/dir/handle"><span></span></a>
```

EDIT:
**test.php:**

```
<?php
function convertURL($url) {
  return preg_replace("/<a href=\"([^\"]+?)\">.*/", "<a href=\"$1\"><span></span></a>", $url);
}

foreach(['<a href="http://linkedin.com/some/vanity"><span></span>some text here</a>', '<a href="http:www.example.com/dir/handle"><span></span>some text here</a>'] as $url) {
  echo "$url => ";
  echo convertURL($url)."\n";
}
```

**php test.php:**

```
$ php /tmp/test.php
<a href="http://linkedin.com/some/vanity"><span></span>some text here</a> => <a href="http://linkedin.com/some/vanity"><span></span></a>
<a href="http:www.example.com/dir/handle"><span></span>some text here</a> => <a href="http:www.example.com/dir/handle"><span></span></a>
```

Comment: I ended up going this route. Was simpler and cleaner. I update the regex to account for more than 1 URL set. I'll update my code above with the final result.

Comment: I added an additional block of code to my question, trying to incorporate your function. This method makes the most sense to me and is a cleaner approach. But apparently I'm not implementing this correctly. Thoughts?

Comment: @JonnyBorg try removing the `?` from the regex. So that it is `<a href=\"([^\"]+)\">.*?<\/a>`

Comment: Still having issues. So, I refined my question to be more clear and around using Regex as I think this is a cleaner approach.

Comment: I also edited my answer to show my tests. There linkedin works.

Answer (score 0):

Obligatory https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2191572 but this should work.

If I may re-word your requirements then you want to remove stuff in between `</span>` and `</a>`

```
$bad_string = '<a href="http:www.example.com/dir/handle"><span>social icon</span>some text here</a>';

$parts = explode('</span>', $bad_string); // explode on </span> and save the array
array_pop($parts); // remove last element of array which should be "some text here</a>"
$parts[] = '</a>'; // re-add the </a>

$good_string = implode('</span>', $parts); // re-join the array on </span>

echo $good_string;
```

Comment: Correct. That is exactly what I'm after, but the href's for some reason are getting stripped too.

Comment: @JonnyBorg even using my solution?

Comment: @JonnyBorg Could you update your question with the exact `$bad_string` which you are trying to parse? Make sure to point out if there are newlines `\n` or anything because if you have multiple URLs then additional pre-processing will have to be performed

Comment: @JonnyBorg Any luck with this?